# Trouble in calculating the covariance matrix

Tags: python, statistics, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the covariance matrix for a dummy dataset using the following formula, but it's not matching with the actual result.

[image]

Let's say the dummy dataset contains three features, *#rooms*, *sqft* and *#crimes*. Each column is a feature vector, and we have 5 data points. I'm creating this dataset using the following code:

```
matrix = np.array([[2., 3., 5., 1., 4.], 
                   [500., 700., 1800., 300., 1200.], 
                   [2., 1., 2., 3., 2.]])
```

Let's normalize the data, so the mean becomes zero.

```
D = matrix.shape[0]
for row in range(D):
    mean, stddev = np.mean(matrix[row,:]), np.std(matrix[row,:])   
    matrix[row,:] = (matrix[row,:] - mean)/stddev
```

Now, I can write a naive covariance calculator that looks at all possible pairs of features, and that works perfectly.

```
def cov_naive(X):
    """Compute the covariance for a dataset of size (D,N) 
    where D is the dimension and N is the number of data points"""
    D, N = X.shape
    covariance = np.zeros((D, D))

    for i in range(D):
        for j in range(i, D):                      
            x = X[i, :]
            y = X[j, :]
            sum_xy = np.dot(x, y) / N
            if i == j:
                covariance[i, j] = sum_xy
            else:                        
                covariance[i, j] = covariance[j, i] = sum_xy
    return covariance
```

But, if I try to implement the formula mentioned in the beginning, the result is incorrect. The method I am trying out is as follows:

```
def cov_naive_2(X):
    """Compute the covariance for a dataset of size (D,N) 
    where D is the dimension and N is the number of data points"""
    D, N = X.shape
    covariance = np.zeros((D, D))

    for i in range(N):                     
        x = X[:, i]
        covariance += x @ x.T
    return covariance / N
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Expected output**:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.96833426, -0.4472136 ],
       [ 0.96833426,  1.        , -0.23408229],
       [-0.4472136 , -0.23408229,  1.        ]])
```

**Actual output from cov_naive_2**

```
array([[3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3.]])
```

Comment: Can you add your expected and yielded outputs?

Comment: @RomainReboulleau added. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is mathematically right, your problem comes from the fact that `numpy` matrix multiplication defaults to inner product when providing vectors, independently from them being transposed to row or column.

Try modifying the penultimate line like this to force outer product.

````py
def cov_naive_2(X):
    """Compute the covariance for a dataset of size (D,N) 
    where D is the dimension and N is the number of data points"""
    D, N = X.shape
    covariance = np.zeros((D, D))

    for i in range(N):                     
        x = X[:, i]
        covariance += np.outer(x, x)  # <---- here
    return covariance / N
```
````